# Filtro de búsqueda en GraphQL con ApiPlatform

Tags: php, symfony, graphql

Tengo un proyecto en **Symfony 5.3** con [ApiPlatform](https://api-platform.com/) y [GraphQL](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/graphql/) en el que tengo una entidad `User` con varios atributos, entre ellos un campo de tipo `array` para los roles. El tema esta que necesito hacer un filtro para buscar los usuarios que tengas específicamente un rol.

```php
  /**
     * @var array
     * @Groups({"user_read","user_write"})
     * @ORM\Column(name="roles", type="array", nullable=false)
     */
    private $roles = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

No he logrado muchos adelantos pero bueno agrego los detalles, siguiendo la doc. he creado un filtro.

```php
#[ApiFilter(
    SearchFilter::class,
    properties: [
    'roles' => 'ipartial'
])]
```

El tema está que al correr la *query* en la herramienta del ***graphiql*** no me esta filtrando.

```
fragment users on User{
   id,
      name,
      email,
      roles
}
{
  users(roles:[ROLE_ADMIN]){
    collection{
     ...users
    }
  }
}
```

Respuesta

```json
{
  "data": {
    "users": {
      "collection": [
        {
          "id": "/api/users/20",
          "name": "Administrator",
          "email": "admin@redman.com",
          "roles": [
            "ROLE_ADMIN",
            "ROLE_USER"
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "/api/users/19",
          "name": "Mr. Jules Balistreri V",
          "email": "estevan.considine@erdman.biz",
          "roles": [
            "ROLE_PATIENT",
            "ROLE_USER"
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "/api/users/18",
          "name": "Macie Herzog",
          "email": "lockman.ramona@gmail.com",
          "roles": [
            "ROLE_ADMIN",
            "ROLE_USER"
          ]
        },
```

He encapsulado el rol a buscar entre comillas(") y entonces la consulta me devuelve resultados vacios.

```
{
  users(roles:["ROLE_ADMIN"]){
    collection{
     ...users
    }
  }
}
```

```json
{
  "data": {
    "users": {
      "collection": []
    }
  }
}
```